# how to use withDynamicRead with KafkaIO in Apache BEAM

Tags: apache-beam, apache-beam-io, apache-beam-kafkaio

I'm using read with KafkaIO in Apache Beam and i'm trying to call [withDynamicRead](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.29.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/kafka/KafkaIO.Read.html#withDynamicRead-org.joda.time.Duration-). I also have a basic call of withCheckStopReadingFn:

```
.withCheckStopReadingFn(new SerializableFunction<TopicPartition, Boolean>() {
   @Override
   public Boolean apply(TopicPartition input) {
     return false;
   }
})
```

I'm getting this error and i can't make sense of it. Anyone know how to call DyanamicRead properly? I'm using Apache Beam version 2.29

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.display.DisplayData$InternalBuilder$PopulateDisplayDataException: Error while populating display data for component 'org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.ParDo$MultiOutput': null
```

Comment: Can you provide the entire invocation of `KafkaIO` and also the the full stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in Beam. Information on contacting the Beam community -devs and other users, and filing bug reports - are at https://beam.apache.org/community/contact-us/